# Unable to use Systemctl commands in centos Docker

Tags: docker, centos, docker-image, systemctl, redhat-containers

I tried to install httpd inside docker container and tried to restart the httpd via systemctl in docker. But I'm getting a exception like below

[image]

As per my analysis systemctl not enabled by default in docker base images, experts suggested to configure like below.

```
    FROM centos:7

ENV container docker
RUN (cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in ; do [ $i == systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done);
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/;
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/.wants/;
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/;
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/udev;
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/initctl;
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/;
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;
VOLUME [ “/sys/fs/cgroup” ]
CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
```

I tried the same but still no luck. Another option I tried using **centos/systemd** as my base image, But no luck.  This is my sample docker file which I'm trying.

```
FROM centos:7
    
RUN  yum -y install httpd php php-mysql php-gd mariadb-server php-xml php-intl mysql weget

RUN systemctl restart httpd.service

RUN  systemctl enable httpd.service
RUN  systemctl start mariadb 

RUN systemctl enable mariadb 

# RUN  mysql -u root -p -u root

EXPOSE 80
```

Any one please advise me on this ? Any other possibilities to achieve the same in different way?

References:

[Docker CentOS systemctl not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52737283/docker-centos-systemctl-not-permitted)
https://forums.docker.com/t/systemctl-status-is-not-working-in-my-docker-container/9075/2

Comment: You may use `service httpd start` instead

Comment: @Saeed - Thanks for the quick suggestion. I tried the same - But it's throwing a command not found error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54961286/bin-sh-service-command-not-found-on-cent-os-7

Comment: `Operation not permited`, try to switch to user with right to restart service

Comment: @Facty - By default docker will have root permission right ?

Answer (score 0):

You should assume systemd don't work in Docker and start your httpd service in your Dockerfile with :

```
CMD ["/usr/sbin/httpd","-D","FOREGROUND"]
```

If you have several services (like your web + database service here), best practise is to split services into several containers that communicate between them.